# Who contacts Captain Marvel in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Captain Marvel shows up for

> the big battle on Earth.

I am curious to know who contacted her because she was likely on another planet when

> Thanos's ship comes through the time machine. Thanos quickly destroyed the Avengers' base so it's highly unlikely that someone contacted her from within that facility.

Perhaps she just happened to be 'in the neighborhood' at this time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Because of the Snap**

Everybody who disappeared is suddenly back. This didn't happen only on earth, but in the whole universe. Therefore Captain Marvel must have noticed that.

The next steps were not shown, but we can assume she tried to contacted the Avengers and nobody answered, or she just started off to Earth, because she knew the Avengers would be involved. Or maybe she was able to detect the energy discharge that is caused by the finger snap and knew where it was coming from (as mentioned by [Paul D. Waite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/440/paul-d-waite])).

There were many things Captain Marvel could have noticed,  so that she didn't have to be called explicitly.

Comment: Nice answer, way better and more logical than mine. +1

Comment: We see at the start of the movie that using all the stones causes an energy discharge that's detectable from a long way away — that's how they find Thanos.

Answer (score 4):

As you said, in all that mess it's not likely someone had a pager at arm's reach, and from the very few appearances of Captain Marvel in the movie, we know she's zooming around in space to saves various planets.

That requires a way to *detect* these planets being threatened to begin with. We see at the beginning that "mere" human tech was able to detect the power surge of the Stones being destroyed some millions of kilometers away. In her solo movie, Kree tech was already *far* more advanced than our own, if you add to that 25 years of progress, and perhaps some Skrull scientists friends, she likely has such a sensor miniaturised and embedded in her suit.

Furthermore, she's part of the gang now and bossed by Black Widow. It's possible, before the Time Heist, that Natasha left instructions to her in case not everyone came back. Or Carol could have just been back for some kind of regular report, or was wondering no one was answering her calls.

Note that her sense of timing was already shown at the beginning of the movie, when she saves Tony and Nebula, without a clear-cut explanation of how she knew where they were.

Comment: Also, Hulk finger snap double the world population, so that should indicate soemthing

Answer (score 0):

In the after credits scene of Avengers:Infinity War you can see how when people starts to dissapear, Nick Fury gets a strange device and try to manipulate it, suddenly, NF dissapears and the device fall to the ground, where you can see it has the symbol of Captain Marvel.

Later, on the Captain Marvel movie, you learn that this device was a communication device she hacked to allow Nick Fury to contact her when the Earth would be in a time of need. Also, at the end of the movie, in the after credits scene, you can see how she arrives at Avengers base and asks Captain America and Black Widow: "Where is Fury?"

Comment: Presumably she could have given the Avengers the same kind of device, but no one was seen paging her, though.

Comment: As far as we know from the movies, she hasn't been on Earth since the end of it's own movie (no other hero or character makes any mention on her until this last movie), as far as we know, only Nick Fury and Agent Coulson know her.

Comment: True, but I meant she could have given them the devices during the 5 years they've been working together in _Endgame_. By the final battle they would have had it... But they didn't (or it wasn't obvious), as no one used a space pager to warn her

Comment: It could be, but we cannot know, as it hasn't been shown on the movie.

Comment: I think you're answering the wrong question. It's about the final battle in Endgame, not about her first meeting with the Avengers. You should at least add "they could have used the same device".

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer, not sure why it has so low votes!